# Google sheets random number generation help

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to generate random numbers in an interval, x number of times.
Imagine rpg dice sintax, like:
3d6 means roll 3 times a dice of 6 sides. Or 5d100 means roll 5 dices of 100 sides.
If I was to generate one x-sided dice y times, how can I do this?.

[image: Image of dice selector]

In this case, on B4, I used:

`IF(B3 = TRUE;RANDBETWEEN(1;4))`

But this only generate one d4.
I want to generate b2 number of d4's, but don't know how.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. May I clarify, please correct me if I am wrong. If you roll a 4-sided dice once, then the result must be a number between 1 and 4. But if Cell B2 equals, say, 2, then you must roll the four sided dice twice. So, let's say we actually roll the dice:, on the first roll it comes up 2, and on the second roll it comes up 1. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation) says "Commonly, these dice are added together". So, should the value in Cell B4 = 3?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

`=IF(B3 = TRUE,RANDBETWEEN((1*B2),(B1*B2)),)`

**Logic**

- If checkbox is ticked - calculate dice roll
- If check box is not ticked, cell is blank
- Dice Roll

  - use `RANDBETWEEN(low, high)`
  - low = 1 multiplied by the number of dice rolls
  - high = number of sides multiplied by the number of dice rolls

---

**RESULT**

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

You need one `RANDBETWEEN` for every throw, so I would do it like this (here without the checkbox):

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1;B1)+IF(B2>1;RANDBETWEEN(1;B1))+IF(B2>2;RANDBETWEEN(1;B1))+IF(B2>3;RANDBETWEEN(1;B1))+...
```

Add as many `IF`s as needed to handle the max number of throws.

Answer (score 0):

### Basic Formula

```
=IF(C4*$K$2, BYROW(SEQUENCE(C3),
    LAMBDA(roll, RANDBETWEEN(1, C2))),)
```

- formula needs to be pasted into each cell of the range `B5:I5`

[image];

### Advanced Single Formula

- Formula is placed only in `B5` and fills in all the other columns.

```
=BYCOL(B2:I4, LAMBDA(col, IF(INDEX(col,3)*K2, 
   BYROW(SEQUENCE(INDEX(col,2)), LAMBDA(roll, 
     RANDBETWEEN(1, INDEX(col, 1)))),)))
```

[image];

### Roll Count Formula [optional]

- This formula in `A5` adds as many "Roll #" entries as needed based on the maximum number of rolls in the current results.

```
=BYROW(B5:I, LAMBDA(r, IF(SUM(r),
  "Roll "& ROW(r)+1-ROW(), IFNA(#N/A))))
```

[image]